# setting up a 5x5 matrix as a char with some options

Tags: c, matrix

I'm trying to program a 5x5 matrix with some options to it. This is what I need to do: (its in german, I hope its not an issue :P)

> Schreiben Sie ein C-Programm, das eine 5*5 Matrix voller + erstellt und diese ausgibt.
> Anschließend soll dem Anwender ein Menü angeboten werden.
> Die Matrix sieht so aus:

- - - - - 
- - - - - 
- - - - - 
- - - - - 
- - - - - 

Optionen:

(1) Fülle alle Felder mit 0

(2) Fülle die beiden Diagonalen mit 0

(3) Fülle ein spezielles Feld mit 0 (Spalte, Zeile)

(4) Refresh: Fülle alle Felder wieder mit +

(5) Ausgabe der Matrix auf dem Bildschirm

(6) Ende des Programms

> 

So far I've got this:

```
#include <stdio.h>


void menue(){
printf("\nOptionen:\n\n");
printf("(1)\tFuelle alle Felder mit 0\n");
printf("(2)\tFuelle die beiden Diagonalen mit 0\n");
printf("(3)\tFuelle ein spezielles Feld mit 0\n");
printf("(4)\tRefresh: Fuelle alle Felder wieder mit +\n");
printf("(5)\tAusgabe der Matrix auf dem Bildschirm\n");
printf("(6)\tEnde des Programms\n");
}

int main () {

const int zeilenanzahl = 5;
const int spaltenanzahl = 5;
char matrix [zeilenanzahl][spaltenanzahl];
int zeile;
int spalte;
int eingabe;

printf("So sieht die Matrix aus: \n\n");

for (zeile = 0; zeile < zeilenanzahl; zeile++) {
    for (spalte = 0; spalte < 5; spalte++){
        matrix [zeilenanzahl][spaltenanzahl] = '+';
        printf("%c ", matrix [zeilenanzahl][spaltenanzahl]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

menue();

do (printf ("Eingabe: "), scanf ("%i",&eingabe));
    while (7 > eingabe > 0);
        printf ("ungueltige Eingabe!");
if (eingabe == 1)
    printf ("testest");

return 0;
}
```

my question is, do I need to use a do while loop? or is it a switch case? Any hints or help is appreciated.

cheers.

Comment: Your code, because it is in german, is significantly harder(at least for me) to understand, as it's not clear to me what the variables are meant to do.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to process those 7 options and print them accordingly.

```
do (printf ("Eingabe: "), scanf ("%i",&eingabe));
    while (7 > eingabe > 0);
```

Here, you are taking your inputs in a do-while loop. So, You'd want to process the options inside the loop itself. I would prefer a  switch..case. You and also use a if..else if.

Here I modified your code to process input (1).

```
do {
        printf ("Eingabe: ");
        scanf ("%i",&eingabe);
        switch(eingabe)
        {
        case 1:
            Fillwithzero(matrix);
            break;

        //other cases go here
        }
}
    while (7 > eingabe > 0);
```

I would recommend to do the processing in separate functions. Also, It's better to have a `print_matrix()` function for easiness.

Note: I used google translate to translate your options. I recommend to ask in english when you are asking for help.